# Округление в генераторах списков

Tags: python, список

Как в python в генераторах списков сделать чтобы если число больше какого то n сделать его равным нулю?

```
for i in range(5):
   for k in range(5):
     if k<=i:
       list.append(k)
     else:
       list.append(0)
```

Мне нужно именно в генераторах списков. Такое вообще можно сделать?

```
a = [[k for k in range(n) if k<=i] for i in range(n)]
```

Вот до чего я пока дошел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу

```
a = [[k if k <= i else 0 for k in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Я не могу поставить лайк и галочку потму что только что зарегистрировал аккаунт

Comment: @Anonim ничего страшного. Пожалуйста.